# SQLAlchemy join two models and select top row

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently I have two tables: Server and Scan.

 It is possible to have one server to many scans (one to many relationship).

What I am trying to achieve is to select a Server and then only the first Scan associated to that Server. The following query:

```
query = db.session.query(models.Server, models.Scan).outerjoin(models.Server.scans).all()
```

outputs:

```
(<Server u'Testing'>, <Scan u'bbd4f805-3966-d464-b2d1-0079eb89d69708c3a05ec2812bcf'>)
(<Server u'Testing'>, <Scan u'bbd4f805-3966-d464-b2d1-0079eb89d69708c3a05ec2812bcf'>)
(<Server u'Testing'>, <Scan u'testscan'>)
(<Server u'fasd'>, <Scan u'testscan'>)
(<Server u'fdaafas'>, None)
```

whereas I only want one "`Testing`" Server and the most recent Scan.

ADDITIONAL

When I loop through my query like so:

```
for a in query:
    print a, a.scans.all()
```

The output is:

```
<Server u'Testing'> [<Scan u'testscan'>, <Scan u'bbd4f805-3966-d464-b2d1-0079eb89d69708c3a05ec2812bcf'>, <Scan u'bbd4f805-3966-d464-b2d1-0079eb89d69708c3a05ec2812bcf'>]
<Server u'fasd'> [<Scan u'testscan'>]
<Server u'fdaafas'> []
```

The output I want should equal:

```
<Server u'Testing'> [<Scan u'bbd4f805-3966-d464-b2d1-0079eb89d69708c3a05ec2812bcf'>]
<Server u'fasd'> [<Scan u'testscan'>]
    <Server u'fdaafas'> []
```

Comment: Using first() instead of all() should work fine.

Comment: First() only selects the first row... I want to select the first scan of every server.

Comment: Is it only in this query, or also in other cases you need the *latest* Scan of the server without loading all Scans into memory?

Comment: loop through the resultset and hold a temp value that says whether or not you did that server yet, so if server has visited, skip it something like ` for u,v in query: `
    if u.servername in [visted list]:
         pass `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a subquery in which you select the `Scan` register you want to show, using some criteria. For the toy example below I assume you want the maximum value of some parameter.

I've created tables `A` and `B`; `A` corresponds to `Server` and `B` to `Scan`.

```
In [2]:

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'A'
​
    pk = Column('pk', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'B'
​
    pk = Column('pk', Integer, primary_key=True)
    fk = Column('fk', Integer, ForeignKey('A.pk'))
    attr = Column('attr', Integer)
​
    a = relationship("A", backref='B')
```

Inserted some data,

```
In [10]:

q = session.query(B)
print(q)
for x in q.all():
    print(x.pk, x.fk, x.attr)

q = session.query(A)
print(q)
for x in q.all():
    print(x.pk, x.name)
​
SELECT "B".pk AS "B_pk", "B".fk AS "B_fk", "B".attr AS "B_attr" 
FROM "B"
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 2 0
4 2 4
5 1 4
SELECT "A".pk AS "A_pk", "A".name AS "A_name" 
FROM "A"
1 one
2 two
```

And solved your problem adding a subquery that selects the maximum value of `B.attr` for every `B.fk`, i.e. for every `A.pk`. (In your example it would be the maximum `Scan.attr` for every `Server`.)

```
In [13]:


from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
​
s = session.query(func.max(B.attr), B.fk).group_by(B.fk)
print(s)
q = session.query(A, B).outerjoin(B).filter(tuple_(B.attr, B.fk).in_(s))
print(q)
for x in q.all():
    print(x.A.pk, x.A.name, x.B.pk, x.B.attr)

SELECT max("B".attr) AS max_1, "B".fk AS "B_fk" 
FROM "B" GROUP BY "B".fk
SELECT "A".pk AS "A_pk", "A".name AS "A_name", "B".pk AS "B_pk", "B".fk AS "B_fk", "B".attr AS "B_attr" 
FROM "A" LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A".pk = "B".fk 
WHERE ("B".attr, "B".fk) IN (SELECT max("B".attr) AS max_1, "B".fk AS "B_fk" 
FROM "B" GROUP BY "B".fk)
2 two 4 4
1 one 5 4
```

NOTE: you don't mention which database you are using, but just in case, please note that the `in_` statement with multiple columns does not work in `sqlite` (which is quite annoying when you try it). But if you used one column only, something like,

```
s = session.query(func.max(B.attr)).group_by(B.fk)
q = session.query(A, B).outerjoin(B).filter(B.attr.in_(s))
```

however depending on your data you could get more than one B for each A (e.g. `B.fk`=1 has max(`B.attr`)=3, and `B.fk`=2 has max(`B.attr`)=4 but also a `B.attr`=3, you would get for `B.fk`=2 both `B.attr`=3 and `B.attr`=4.

However if the attribute you are using to select the maximum was unique, it would be fine. Anyway if you are with a database like `postgres` or `oracle` you can use the `in_` with multiple columns.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT added after comments:**
If you want to get also the `Servers` without a `Scan`, you just need to add an `or_` to your query.

```
In [18]:

from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy import tuple_
from sqlalchemy import or_
​
s = session.query(func.max(B.attr), B.fk).group_by(B.fk)
q = session.query(A, B).outerjoin(B).filter(or_(tuple_(B.attr, B.fk).in_(s), B.fk==None))
print(q)
for x in q.all():
    if x.B:
        print(x.A.pk, x.A.name, x.B.pk, x.B.attr)
    else:
        print(x.A.pk, x.A.name)
​
SELECT "A".pk AS "A_pk", "A".name AS "A_name", "B".pk AS "B_pk", "B".fk AS "B_fk", "B".attr AS "B_attr" 
FROM "A" LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" ON "A".pk = "B".fk 
WHERE ("B".attr, "B".fk) IN (SELECT max("B".attr) AS max_1, "B".fk AS "B_fk" 
FROM "B" GROUP BY "B".fk) OR "B".fk IS NULL
2 two 4 4
1 one 5 4
3 three
```

As you see, you have to be careful with nulls. Note that `outerjoin` already performs a `left join`, which is what you needed, but because of the `filter`, you have to explicitly say that you want the null rows also. As usual, `A` is `Server` and `B` is `Scan`. Sorry for not using your table names, it makes it much more difficult to read.

Comment: Hi @lrnzcig, Thank you for your answer, although I am finding it slightly difficult to understand so I thought I'd provide further information to my problem.
 I have modified my question a little to provide a better explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I read your update but still I don't understand. What is the "last" `Scan` for you? Do you have any criteria for selecting that "last one", or it is just the last one you get from the ddbb? If you can set some criteria, then you may be able to use my answer (and if it is not well explained, just tell me what is it you're finding trouble with...) And indeed if you don't have any criteria to select the "last" then you should use another strategy... Please let me know

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing you a little. Just to note, the DB I am using is sqlite, so the above query does not work.
I am using the scan id as the criteria. So when I select a Server, I want to the last Scan associated to that Server.

Comment: This actually works perfectly!! Super sorry, I was writing the commands in incorrectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: So, if you are using `sqlite`, the solution will work if the `scan_id` is unique, by using the last 2 queries. If it is unique, please tell me, and I can modify the answer and try to make it more clear.

Comment: sorry, one more question. How can I output a server if it has no scan associated to it. So there is no scan_id on a server?